# Facebook Open Graph - 'Like Button' - Hidden Content Revealed Upon 'Like'

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I was wondering, I wish to have a landing page with Facebook's Open Graph (specifically the like button) and I wanted to basically have content set to  display:none (can't remember the specific  until a user likes a page. An example being a div on an e-commerce store that when a user likes the page, the div is set to display:block and users can redeem a coupon code for discount.

I would like to be able to do this with div displays.

I saw this little snippet of code on the Facebook developers forum:

**| ( taken from http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:like )**
*(Note: The event that's fired when you click "like")*

```
<script>
  // this will fire when any of the like widgets are "liked" by the user
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    Log.info('You liked ' + href, widget);
  });
</script>
```

Can this be modified to effective set a div from display:none to display:block?

Thank you SO.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following solution, but you will need jQuery to do it. (possibly not, but that's what I used to do it).

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="facebook.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: '133387220039676', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
 // Do something, e.g. track the click on the "Like" button here
    $('#slidingDiv').show();
 });
};
(function() {
 var e = document.createElement('script');
 e.type = 'text/javascript';
 e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
 e.async = true;
 document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());
//-->
</script>
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/TheRightMind" layout="standard" show-faces="false" width="450" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>

<div id="slidingDiv" style="display:none;">
Fill this space with really interesting content that you can
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want to update your div to `display:block`, use...

```
<script>
  // this will fire when any of the like widgets are "liked" by the user
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    $('#divid').css('display','block');
  });
</script>
```

One caveat...

Your `edge.create` event WON'T fire unless the URL you use as part of your  call is EXACTLY the same as the URL you're attempting to fire this from.

I had a site I was running on *example.DEV* (my local laptop dev env) which referenced a link on *example.com* (the live server) and anything in the `FB.Event.subscribe()` block wouldn't run until I uploaded the file, and fired it from the LIVE server.

That could be why you're having trouble if it's not working so far!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `Log.info()` call with JavaScript that displays the `div`. In jQuery:

```
<script>
  // this will fire when any of the like widgets are "liked" by the user
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    $('#yourdiv').show();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still having major problems with this, I can't seem to get any solution to work. I know this is a huge ask for such a helpless member but could you possibly provide the div format to accompany this code  for it to work? Thank you for your time ceejay.

Answer (score 0):

After verifying that liking the page will trigger that code (try `console.log("AOK!")`), you can make a `<div>` appear using this code:

**Plain Old JavaScript:**

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
  document.getElementById("topsecret").style.display = "block";
});
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="topsecret" style="display:none;">
  Content Goes Here
</div>
```

If you're using the jQuery library or something similar, you can use a `show()` function to make the box appear instead:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
  $("#topsecret").show();
  //$("#topsecret").slideDown("fast");
  //$("#topsecret").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

You might also consider using an AJAX load command instead, because otherwise it's fairly easy to make the box appear when the content is only hidden.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
  $("#topsecret").load("mycontent.html");
});
```